# Hubot Google Calendar Free Busy says timemin not set

Tags: coffeescript, google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to write a hubot script to poll Google Calendar for the free-busy information of each calendar. The problem is that the request is returning an error message:  `Missing timeMin parameter`, even though timeMin is set in the body.

```
module.exports = (robot) ->
robot.respond /ar|what (room|rooms) (is|are) available\?|available (rooms|room)\?/i, (msg) ->
apiKey = 'MyAPIkey'
url = "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/freeBusy?key=#{ apiKey }"
d = new Date()
now = d.toISOString()
endOfDay = "#{ now.substr(0, 11) }23:59:59#{ now.substr(19) }"

roomCalendars = []

for alias, room of rooms
  roomCalendars.push room.id

post_data = JSON.stringify({
  'timeMin': now
  'timeMax': endOfDay
  items: roomCalendars
})

robot.http(url)
  .post(post_data) (err, res, body) ->
      if err or res.statusCode isnt 200
          msg.send 'I\'ve encountered an error trying to get an available room. Sorry!'
          return
        msg.send 'Here'
```

This returns:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Missing timeMin parameter."
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Missing timeMin parameter."
 }
}
```

post_data is:

```
{"timeMin":"2014-08-07T18:11:27.761Z","timeMax":"2014-08-07T23:59:59.761Z","items":[{"id":"id1"},{"id":"id2"},{"id":"id3"},{"id":"id4"},{"id":"id5"}]}
```

Comment: Using some network analyzer or any other "debugging utility", have you checked if `timeMin` is really send as a parameter of the POST request?

Comment: @SylvainLeroux I don't really know how I would see if it's actually being sent, but when I print post_data, it is definitely set

Comment: Are you sure it's in the correct time format?

Comment: @thedeadlybutter Yep - copied directly from Google Api's Explorer

Comment: @General_Twyckenham [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) ? That would allow you to check for sure what is really send as a request. Might definitively helps to narrow the issue.